# Sublimetext php-cs-fixer changes namespace to lowercase

Tags: php, laravel-5, sublimetext3, phpcs

While using sublimetext3 in a Laravel project, php-cs-fixer (PHP CS Fixer version 1.12.0) 'fixes' the namespace (App) from Uppercase to lowercase (app).
Eg. `namespace App\Http\Controllers;` to `namespace app\Http\Controllers;`

This causes a Class not found error.

If anyone has a suggestion, I would be grateful. I am also considering not using php-cs-fixer and using phpcbf instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're following a deprecated PHP Standard Recommendation (PSR-0), while [Laravel follows PSR-4](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/13382#issuecomment-215945139).

If you want to continue following PSR-0, try adding this to your `phpcs.sublime-settings`:

```
"php_cs_fixer_additional_args": {
    "--fixers": "-psr0"
}
```

You can find the settings in the menu: *Preferences > PHP Code Sniffer > Settings - User*

Comment: Thanks @idleberg for the PSR-4 link and where to change it. Very helpful, even in 2019.